# Descarga de archivo en Python

Tags: python

Tengo una pregunta,

¿Cómo puedo descargar un archivo de desde la web, el cual siempre tiene un nombre diferente cuando lo depositan?

Digamos que cada lunes se carga el archivo como Archivo__America_Empresa_dd-mm-hh-mm-ss.xlsx entonces se puede decir que el archivo es va a ser diferente porque el nombre cambia en la parte donde depende del día y la hora. Tengo poca experiencia con Python

¿Se puede hacer algo que solo busque una parte del nombre del archivo (en este caso quiero buscar la parte que no cambia) que necesito descargar?

Gracias

Comment: No está claro si preguntas por: a) Cómo descargar algo via HTTP, b) Cómo generar tú mismo el nombre del archivo a partir de la fecha, c) cómo "buscar" en una página (que tendrías que descargar previamente) el enlace al archivo del día.

Comment: incluso si quieres hacer un webscrapping

Answer (score 1):

si es linux puedes usar:

```
os.system("wget url -O ruta/de/salida")
```

Con el paquete `os`, otra opción es con el paquete `urllib` de la siguiente forma:

```
import urllib
urllib.urlretrieve ("http://www.example.com/songs/mp3.mp3", "mp3.mp3")
```